# Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova_plugin_googlemaps

Tags: cordova, google-maps, angular, ionic2

I try to build an app using ionic 2 & angular 2. where i want to integrate google maps within it. But whenever i try to add cordova plugins using the following commands.

```
cordova plugin add cordova_plugin_googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="API_KEY_GOES_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="API_KEY_GOES HERE"
```

But, it throws an error like below:

```
Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova_plugin_googlemaps
```

I don't understand what is the problem and why it throws this error. But i tried to solve this problem by setting the registry using bellowing command

```
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

unfortunately, it doesn't work. It would be helpful to me if anyone suggest me how can i get rid off this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake by inverting _ with -. The good name of the plugin is `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` and not `cordova_plugin_googlemaps`